# Z Scores and finding Distribution amounts

Tags: statistics

A distribution has a standard deviation of o=10. Find the z-score for each of the following locations in the distribution.

a) Above the mean by 5 points
b) Above the mean by 2 points
c) Below the mean by 20 points
d) Below the mean by 15 points

Please don't give me the answer, but explain how I would work this out.

Comment: Is this all the information you were given?

Answer (score 1):

If a given distribution $X$ is normal with some mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma = 10$, then the **standardized** value is given by $$Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}.$$  This standardized value is a $z$-score, and represents the number of standard deviations above/below the mean the original $X$ was observed to be.

For example, suppose that the height $X$ of a particular species of plant is normally distributed with mean $\mu = 87$ centimeters and standard deviation $10$ centimeters.  Then if I randomly select one such plant from the population and measure it, and find that it is $X = 97$ centimeters tall, then this corresponds to a $z$-score of $$Z = \frac{97 - 87}{10} = 1.$$  So in this particular instance, this plant's height is **1 standard deviation above the mean**.  That makes sense:  $87 + 10 = 97$.

Now, if I don't know what the population mean is, but I know that the standard deviation is still $\sigma = 10$, then I can say that if a measurement is $5$ units above the mean, that is equivalent to a $z$-score of...??? (you fill in the blank), because $5$ units above the mean is equivalent to ??? standard deviations above the mean.

Similarly, if I say that a measurement is below the mean by $20$ points (or units), then that must be how many standard deviations below the mean?  Remember that if we are below the mean, then we should express that as a *negative* $z$-score.